# How to correctly wait for fetch in a react class

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have a class where I have to check for existence of item to display in one html form(say hyperlink) or normal text.

I get the object as a prop. I am finding it hard to use fetch to correctly recognise if the item exists based on return code

```
    this.props.item.map(function(item) {
          fetch(url+item)(). then (
              if(statusCode === 200)
                 //display hyperlink
                 return <a href=url+item>{item.a:item.b}</a>
              else
                 //normal text
                 return <disp>{item.a:item.b}</disp>
          )
         // But its expecting a return here!
         //return <disp>{item.a:item.b}</disp>
    })
```

Comment: why are you using map if you aren't doing anything with the returned values (not that you are returning any) - map seems to be the *wrong choice*

Comment: Be careful when programmatically sending requests to user-generated urls from your application, this can lead to some security risks. At least, it sounds like these are user-generated urls, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @JaromandaX What would you recommend I use?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts , Yes its just an append to base url. no xss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this is asynchronous code.

You have a couple of problems:

Firstly, (if I'm right in assuming that's an [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function) the  `.map` function needs to return something. The map function converts one array, into another array of the same size.

Secondly, and more importantly, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

So even if you changed your code to:

```
this.props.item.map(function(item) {
     return fetch(url+item)(). then (
          if(statusCode === 200)
             //display hyperlink
             return <a href=url+item>{item.a:item.b}</a>
          else
             //normal text
             return <disp>{item.a:item.b}</disp>
      )         
})
```

All you would get is an array of promises.

What I recommend you do, is start using [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react), and personally I recommend using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html).

The basic concept with redux and other state management solutions, is that your React components are responsible for *displaying data* and *responding to user interaction* (usually by dispatching a redux action) only. They shouldn't be responsible for actually fetching or manipulating the data. That's what your state management middleware (such as redux-saga) is for.

I won't go into it here, but that should put you in the right direction.

Comment: This answer is correct, but you don't need to recommend an entire library to solve this problem. The general advice is correct, with the additional note that data should be fetched within `componentDidMount()` and in user event callbacks, _not_ the `render()` method. The `render()` function should handle displaying a loading icon while the asynchronous fetch is occurring though. You don't need react-redux or react-saga to do this, they just make it easier to structure that way.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Sure, that's a fair point, and it answers the more immediate question. 

However, mixing your data fetch/business logic in with your components is a surefire way to create some really messy and difficult-to-work with code.

Comment: One last note, when the batch of data being fetched is complete, use the `setState()` method after it's all loaded (most likely using `Promise.all()` to aggregate your promises) to instruct the React component to re-render itself using the newly available data in its state.

Comment: Yes, and one thing I like about react-redux is it provides a way to write your business logic into a HOC that can be used to compose your component, allowing the logic to be separable. But it's not vital for the component to work with asynchronous data sources.